# How to update two columns in one query, one from another?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Is it possible to update two columns, one of them from another's value in one PostgreSQL query?

Let me explain it. If I had this table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id bigint,
  val1 integer,
  val2 integer
);
```

and insert there a row:

```
INSERT INTO test (id, val1, val2) VALUES (1, NULL, NULL);
```

Then I need to update `val1` and `val2` columns. For `val1` I set explicit value, for `val2` I use `val1` column's value.

```
UPDATE test
SET 
  val1 = 1,
  val2 = val1
WHERE id = 1
```

I expect to set `val1` to `1` and val2 to `1` as a reference to just set `val1`. However, after this update I get `1` in `val1` column and `NULL` in `val2`.

Of course, it isn't real life example. In my real problem I set `val1` value with several conditions, so I wouldln't like to copy part of them again to `val2` value.

Is it possible to do this like I expect in one query?

Comment: No. `val1` on the right-hand-side of the expression will always refer to the existing value of `val1`. You could do it with a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to repeat conditions, you can define them in the query.  For instance:

```
UPDATE test
    SET val1 = v.new_val1,
        val2 = v.new_val1
    FROM (VALUES (1)) v(new_val1)
    WHERE id = 1;
```